# Is there a problem with concurrent calls to executable files in EFS

Tags: amazon-web-services, filesystems, amazon-efs

I store some executable files in EFS, and then I will execute these executable files in my k8s pod or lambda function through the command line. My question is when I call these executables concurrently, is there some problem like lock conflict etc.

The reason why I mount executable files by EFS (these executable files are actually freesurfer) is mainly because they are too large. If they are packaged in a docker image, the image size will be too large.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what these `executables` are doing. If they write/modify the same files or databases, then there will be issues related to race conditions. In contrast, if they do not need to modify any shared resources, then there is no any special locks on EFS to stop you from running them in parallel.